# Prove $H = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^* : x^2 \text{ is rational}\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $\mathbb{R}^*$ be the group of nonzero real numbers under multiplication and let
>   $$H = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^* : x^2 \text{ is rational}\}.$$
>   Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^*$.

I have so far that $H$ is nonempty because $e=1$ is in $H$ since $e^2$ is rational. Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of $H$. We know that $a^2$ and $b^2$ are rational.

We need to show that $ab^{-1}$ is in $\mathbb{R}^*$ and that $(ab^{-1})^2$ is rational.

I'm having trouble with this last part mainly because I'm not sure how to show that $b^{-1}$ is also an element of $H$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: $(ab^{-1})^2=a^2(b^{-1})^2={a^2\over b^2}.$ Now, $a^2$ and $b^2$ are both rational . . .

(To see that $b^{-1}\in H$, just think about $(b^{-1})^2={1\over b^2}$ . . .)

Comment: I wasn't sure whether I could assume that $(ab^{-1})^2$ = $a^2(b^{-1})^2$ because this is necessarily only true for Abelian groups. Would I first have to show that R* is Abelian before I can make this assumption?

Comment: Not if you already know the basic properties of $\mathbb{R}$. I suspect that you are allowed to use the fact that real multiplication is commutative.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the argument of Noah Schweber carefully it can also be adapted to prove that nonzero real numbers whose $n$th powers are rational numbers form a subgroup. (fixing an $n$, of course ). This is because $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$.

If you have studied about homomorphisms this can be put this way:
In abelian groups the function $g\mapsto g^n$ is a homomorphism of that group  to itself.

This fact, along with another result that inverse image of a subgroup under a homomorphism is again a subgroup proves this.